# JQuery plugin isn't working after integration of existing webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html file with an Ajax form submit and plain Javascript functions.

Now I used jQuery plugin for Resizing, Dragging, Dropping and Swapping(plugin).

It works perfectly locally but when I upload it onto a server it works partially

except Swapping(Dragging & Dropping).

Any idea please.

Comment: No need to format text as code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works at locally it means there isn't any problem in function. I guess Only reason could be :

**1. js file is not loading from server to local machine

2. if js file loads then function is not invoking somehow.**

Please go through only by these two steps and then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check your include javascript path. And with firebug if all the ressources have been successfully loaded.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I debugged using firebug and found that related function isn't loading somehow that's why it's not working. now what to do ?

Comment: and all your js files are successfully loaded ?

Comment: it loads at first time only and works perfectly but when DIV updates further by ajax then one function doesn't work.I think all js files loads successfully but the function is not invoked by updated div because of i don't see the particular function in firebug after first time load.